IBM fake backend vs real backend
It is claimed that the fake backends of IBM will have noise similar to the real backends. However, to what extent can we expect them to produce the same results?
I have run my quantum circuit on the real backend, ibm_kyoto and the result differs vastly from the fake backends (FakeCairoV2, FakeTorino) which I test my algorithm with.
Do the real backends have much more noise than the fake ones?

To do a proper comparison you should compare the real backend ibm_kyoto to the fake backend fake_kyoto.

Related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/37673/10454

@mathias There seems to be another issue with that: the transpiler turns my 20 qubit circuit to a circuit with same num of qubits as the real backend. So it becomes 127 qubit circuit whose simulation takes too much memory. I am guessing this is the case because I have error message 'not enough memory' when I try it on FakeTorino().

@DerenLiu One thing you could do is to construct a custom fake backend using the calibration data of the subset of qubits that you are using on ibm_kyoto. That way you can simulate locally. Do you think this is what you want? I can write a detailed answer on that.

Fake backends from qiskit-IBM-runtime package contains calibration results from a snapshot that is hardcoded in the source code. To get a more realistic simulation results, you can use qiskit-aer with the latest calibration results:
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService

service = QiskitRuntimeService()
real_backend = service.backend('ibm_kyoto')
aer_simulator = AerSimulator.from_backend(real_backend)

You can read more in the documentation about different local testing modes: https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/verify/local-testing-mode
